# Running Total in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, cumulative-sum

I have an SwiftUI app that records costs for various items.  I want to display a running total at the top of the main page but can't think how to do it.  Users enter an amount in a TextField `(@State private var amount = 0.0)`  which displays in the individual transaction which is one of many.  How can I keep the running total??  Got me stumped.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: look up using `reduce`

Comment: We know nothing about your data model or how your code is structured so we can’t help you solve this. Improve the question if you really want some help

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and of course show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Sorry for the lack of details.  I have reposted the question.